# How to check if a method is available in an OCX interface

Tags: delphi

Currently I have an OCX embedded in our product using standard boilerplate Delphi importing of the OCX.  The vendor has issued a new version of the OCX that uses the exact same GUIDs for everything (object and interfaces) but there are changes to the API.  These changes are quite limited but I'm having some difficulty coming up with a reliable way to identify if the installed OCX is using the old or new version.  The obvious way is to drill into the interface and check if a specific method is available from the object once it has been instantiated.  I would like to do this by actually asking the object what the dispatch ID is for a particular method to see if it is present.

I don't want to use the approach of calling a new method and getting an exception as the object won't work until it has been initialised and the initialisation API is one of the things that has changed.  This means that any call of a new method before initialisation will fail anyway.

Does anyone know what would be the proper way to poke through the Delphi wrapper and find out if a particular method can be resolved?

Comment: "*The vendor has issued a new version of the OCX that uses the exact same GUIDs for everything (object and interfaces) but there are changes to the API*" - then the vendor has violated core requirements of COM, namely DO NOT change interfaces and DO NOT reuse GUIDs for new/changed functionality. This needs to be called out as a bug on their part. If they needed to change existing APIs, it should have been done using new interlaces with new GUIDs, for exactly this reason

Comment: @Remy, unfortunately the big ugly vendor is not going to take any notice and their real customers (the end user) are just going to turn to us and say "what are you going to do about it" .  I've had experience of this sort of thing before and know it would be a complete waste of time to harass them.  Since they've dropped the old API it should be new GUIDs for everything.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually in your question:

> I would like to do this by actually **asking the object what the dispatch ID is for a particular method** to see if it is present.

An OCX object implements the `IDispatch` interface, and `IDispatch` has a [`GetIDsOfNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-getidsofnames) method for the very purpose of returning the dispatch ID of the object's methods and properties (for use with `IDispatch.Invoke()`). If a requested name is not known to the object, `GetIDsOfNames()` returns `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME`.

Comment: I appreciate the theory but Delphi classes implement this as well.  In this case do I need to extract the IDispatch interface from the Delphi wrapper and ask it direct or will asking the Delphi wrapper class work.  I'm guessing the Delphi wrapper class may respond based on its own internal RTTI rather than asking the OCX.  Can you confirm either way or is this very much a try it out sort of situation.

Comment: @Kanitatlan you'll just have to try it out and see what happens